# Build do React Native não atualiza as configurações

Tags: react-native

Recentemente fiz build de um projeto com o nome "projeto1" seguindo os passos da [documentação](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android) e desde esse projeto todos os meus outros projetos estão tendo o mesmo nome desse projeto, eu mudo as configurações de build e é como se eu não tivesse mudado nada, as únicas coisas que estão atualizando é o código do App.js e o ícone do app, as configurações de build como mudar o nome do app, gerar apk universal e gerar um apk pra cada arquitetura de CPU estão sendo ignoradas e seguindo as configurações de build do primeiro app que fiz compilei nessa máquina.

OBS: Já criei Vários Apps com o comando `react-native init nameApp` e eles seguem o mesmo padrão de build do primeiro app, além de não aparecer nenhum erro para que eu possa estar compartilhando aqui

Answer (score 1):

Eu tive um problema parecido. Eu utilizo Windows e testo usando o emulador Genymotion. Começou a dar um problema onde as alterações que eu fazia funcionavam corretamente no emulador, mas, ao gerar um signed APK e instalar no aparelho, estas alterações não apareciam.

Os comandos que eu usava para caso de problemas não funcionaram, como estes:

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```

ou

```
cd android
gradlew clean
```

No meu caso, o problema foi resolvido ao executar este comando:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

Depois de executar este comando, eu gerei um novo signed APK (gradlew assembleRelease) e o problema no aparelho deixou de ocorrer.